# Is there a way of expressing the linear problem $Ax=b$ as an eigenvalue problem $Bu=\lambda u$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a way of expressing the linear problem $Ax=b$ as an eigenvalue problem $Bu=\lambda u$?

What about the converse?

Comment: The converse is easy: $Bu = \lambda u$ implies $Ax = b$ with $A = B - \lambda E, x = u$ and $b = 0$.

Comment: There's a trivial way: Let $B=[A| b]$ (plus a row of zeros at the bottom); then the $0$-eigenvector $By=0y$, where $y=(y_0,t)$, gives $Ay_0+tb=0$, so $x=-y_0/t$. But maybe you seek more?

Comment: Finding an eigenvalue of $B$ is equivalent to finding a root of the characteristic polynomial of $B$. Since there is "no quintic equation" (that is, no equation for a root of a general polynomial of degree 5 or greater), we can't hope to find a direct method for solving eigenvalue problems, and we must resort to iterative methods. However, direct methods are available to solve $Ax = b$. For example, Cramer's rule provides an explicit formula for a solution (although that's not the most efficient way to compute the solution, of course).